# How to maintain different Python installations that would work across different devices and environments?

Tags: python

I am constantly battling to make sure my Python installations are up to date and as close to identical as possible between all the different machines and devices I use (eg, raspberry pi's, desktop PC's and laptops).

My latest frustration stems specifically from a practical example where I have two identical Pi Zero W's running the exact same Python script. One works perfectly while the other complains about urllib3, even though both Pi's run DietPi with the same versions of Python etc.

I find it similarly frustrating just keeping and maintaining one version of Python and libs on one PC, then if you throw a Mac into the mix that seemingly has its own "dedicated" Python installation.

Is there some elegant solution to this that is easily transferable between devices etc? Perhaps something like having a "master" python installation somewhere that I can clone or "package" and then move along with the script so I know it will work on any device I plonk it on, and will remain working regardless of some update in future? A Docker container would work, but I am pretty sure it will be too big for a Pi Zero.

I know about the venv's, but I am not sure if this is something that I can "copy and paste" between devices. Again, ideally, I'd like to create the code on my PC, and just be able to copy the python file(s) to another device and know that it will run the same everywhere.

Comment: Docker is definitely my first thought. Have you tried it?

Comment: What errors happen when you actually use enviroments using venv/ conda? Enviroments are designed to be sandboxed, atleast to a large extent and dont rely on the base installation.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to remove the rant parts and focus on one issue? It is really hard to make out what you are actually asking, and the concrete points cover a huge range of topics.

Comment: Package your scripts. Put precise dependencies in `setup.py` (or, going forward, `pyproject.toml` which is the emerging replacement for the old convention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing some code that work on any Python environment and will continue to do whatever the updates is hopeless except for really trivial code (`print ('Hello')` should give same results whatever the Python version but is not really interesting).

AFAIK, the only reasonable way is to package your own code, in the sense of the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/). The packaging will manage the dependencies and the Python versions so if you can install it with some `/path/to/python -m pip install` (resp. `py -x -m pip install` for Windows without venv), then it should work with the same python that was used for installation.

It does require some initial work to understand Python Packaging and building the packages but it should save you some headaches when installing your application on a new environment... And if you want to be able to have various Python applications requiring potentially incompatible versions of libraries, `venv` is definitely the solution: you build a venv, install your own package in it, and find exactly the dependencies you need with the proper versions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - is it possible to "copy&paste" a venv? I'm reading up on your Packaging User Guide now...